Asset transaction PENDING but didn't send stellar
I have a code that should send an AQUA coin to another address. RPC Quicknode responds that the transaction is pending and gives a hash. But nothing happens, I can't find the transaction by the hash, what could be the reason? The sender's wallet is GAUL3AJIJE2DKJXAZDYUBM6RB7NJ2S7OB2KDA6ZU7TAR3SA3DF3OHV22. I know for a fact that there is a trustline at the recipient's address.
async createAssetTransaction(receiver: string, amount: number, assetCode: string, assetIssuer: string) {
let _receiver = "GAGN5YWP6EGHGBFD2O7FVHCXCVE5V2I6BFUJUCHRCFIC7RCAQIX4QTUX"
let _amount = 1000
let _assetCode = "AQUA"
let _assetIssuer = "GBNZILSTVQZ4R7IKQDGHYGY2QXL5QOFJYQMXPKWRRM5PAV7Y4M67AQUA"

const sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(this.stellarConfigService.walletSecretKey);
const sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();

const account = await this.stellarServer.getAccount(sourcePublicKey)

const asset = new Asset(_assetCode, _assetIssuer)

let transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, {
  networkPassphrase: StellarSdk.Networks.PUBLIC,
  fee: "1000"
}).addOperation(
  Operation.payment({
    destination: _receiver,
    amount: _amount.toString(),
    asset: asset,
  }),
).setTimeout(30).build()

transaction.sign(sourceKeypair)

const result = await this.stellarServer.sendTransaction(transaction)
return  result}

